# Locally scoped begin-end declares (altering multiple triggers in a single transaction)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Goal**

I need to alter a number of almost identical triggers on a number of tables (and a number of databases).
Therefore I wan't to make one big script, and perform all the changes in one succeed-or-fail transaction.

**My first attempt** (that doesn't work)

```
---First alter trigger
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_UserGarbleValue] ON [dbo].[users]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
    DECLARE @GarbleValue NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @NewID NVARCHAR(20)

    SET @NewID = (SELECT TOP 1 usr_id FROM users ORDER BY usr_id DESC)

    SET @GarbleValue = dbo.fn_GetRandomString(4) + @NewID + dbo.fn_GetRandomString(4)

    UPDATE users SET usr_garble_value = @GarbleValue WHERE usr_id = @NewID
End
Go

--Subsequent alter trigger (there would be many more in the real-world usage)
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_SegmentGarbleValue] ON [dbo].[segment]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
    DECLARE @GarbleValue NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @NewID NVARCHAR(20)

    SET @NewID = (SELECT TOP 1 seg_id FROM segment ORDER BY seg_id DESC)

    SET @GarbleValue = dbo.fn_GetRandomString(4) + @NewID + dbo.fn_GetRandomString(4)

    UPDATE segment SET seg_garble_value = @GarbleValue WHERE seg_id = @NewID
End
Go
```

Running each of the alter trigger statements by themselves works fine. But when both of them are run in the same transaction, the declares crash in the second alter because the variables name already exists.

How do I accomplish this? Is there any way to declare a variable locally within a begin-end scope, or do I need to rethink it completely?

(I'm aware that the "top 1" for fetching new records is probably not very clever, but that is another matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've confused `GO` (the batch separator) and transactions. It shouldn't complain about the variable names being redeclared, provided the batch separators are still present:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_UserGarbleValue] ON [dbo].[users]
FOR INSERT
AS
---Etc
Go
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_SegmentGarbleValue] ON [dbo].[segment]
FOR INSERT
AS
---Etc
Go
COMMIT
```

---

As to your note about `TOP 1`, it's worse than you think - a trigger runs once per *statement*, not once per row - it could be running in response to multiple rows having been inserted. And, happily, there is a pseudo-table available (called `inserted`) that contains exactly those rows which caused the trigger to fire - there's no need for you to go searching for those row(s) in the base table.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the Go(;) between the two statements.

Comment: Regarding Top 1: You are right, but it is not currently an issue as the system that writes the data always uses separate inserts (but I think I will change it anyway, so it doesn't break when someone starts doing bulk inserts).